# Custom post pagination trouble

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I do have a problem with a custom post pagination. I search through this site and googled the whole day yesterday, and found nothing that was similar to what I experience (or I'm getting blind...).

Here is my custom post "recipe":

```
register_post_type( 'recipe', array(
'labels' => array(
    'name'               => __('Recipes'),
    'singular_name'      => __('Recipe'),
    'add_new'            => __('Add New'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Add new Recipe'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Recipe'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Edit Recipe'),
    'new_item'           => __('New Recipe'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Recipe'),
    'search_items'       => __('Search Recipes'),
    'not_found'          => __('No Recipes found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Recipes found in Trash'),
),
'public'        => true,
'show_ui'       => true,
'hierarchical'  => true,
'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'menu_position' => 100,
'menu_icon'     => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/icon_recipe.png',
'rewrite'       => array(
    "slug"       => "recipe",
    "with_front" => false,
            "pages"      => true
)
) );
```

I need to load 6 recipes on my recipe page, and then I use jQuery to load the next 6 in AJAX. The code actually grab the "next page" URL (that is hidden in my page) to perform this.

The problem is that it keeps loading the first 6 recipes, despite the fact that the url is correct (/recettes/page/2/).

When I try to load this page directly in the address bar, it redirects to /recettes/ (that is my first page).
Even when I put a die("test") at the top of my template file, it never gets there.
Could it be only related to the URL rewriting?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The strange thing is that the same mechanism works for the news section...
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Matt

PS: here is the page, if you want to have a look: http://www.francoischartier.ca/recettes/

PPS: and this is the news section that works: http://www.francoischartier.ca/chartier/nouvelles/

Here is the query in the page template for recipes:

```
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'recipe',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'order'          => 'ASC',
                'orderby'        => 'post_title',
                'tax_query'      => array(),
                'paged'          => $paged,
                                    'caller_get_posts' => 1
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve it.
The problem was caused by a plugin, 404 Redirected.
It catched my URL and decided that it needed to add a 301 redirection on my URL and then send it to the URL without pagination...

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same. Your news page is the posts page, and your recipes page is a page post type where you've used a custom query to load the posts. I can see that by looking at the classes being added to the body tag. I presume that your custom query has no pagination parameters being passed to it, but you'll have to show us the code in the template to confirm.

If you were to set `has_archive` to `true` when you register your post type and use the post type archive page instead of a custom query, your AJAX pagination will probably work.

Comment: Hi Milo, and thanks for your answer. You're right, I'm using a specific template to display the recipes' page.

I've updated the question with the query performed in the template.

I'll try the post type "page" with "has_archive" = true to see if it works.

Comment: I've change the way I register the post and added
'capability_type'   => 'page','has_archive'   => true.

But it still doesn't work...

Comment: you have to point to that archive instead of the page you're currently using. if you want the archive at `recettes` then set `has_archive` to `recettes` and remove the page. or for testing purposes, try just visiting `recipe`, which is where your archive page is now located.

Comment: Nope, didn't work either...

Comment: I installed the whole site on my computer (WAMP), and surprisingly, it works there, but not online. Any idea of what can be wrong?